# Custom UISwitch?

Tags: ios, customization, uiswitch

For the past three days I have been trying to roll my own UISwitch because it is customized with a custom image for the actual switch button and a custom image for the track. So far it has resulted in bugs and ugly code and it just does not work well.

Since I don't want to re-invent the wheel, are there any ways or libraries that I can use that allow me to customize a UISwitch with my own UIImage's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an almost-complete UISwitch-like control. Since it's opensource, you can subclass/modify it in order to customize it using images.

https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch

Comment: Are you sure there are no libraries that already have the functionality im looking for implemented?

Comment: @iBradApps that's the library :) Or you can make your own.

Comment: Or see the layers approach detailed below.  I don't know if this is a better way of doing it because the original may still be getting rendered under the hood.  There is probably a way to disable it.  In the end, I'd go with the way that is the most maintainable and has the best performance.

Comment: I accepted because I managed to fix my own custom implementation of a UISwitch but using UIButtons, but I recommend to anyone else to just use this library instead since it took me quite a while to perfect my own code.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a completely custom version of the switch using layers.

Below is a simple example.  You should be able to modify this to use Images or whatever custom graphics you feel like drawing.

Instead of the standard looking switch, it uses red and green fill to indicate on/off state.  It behaves the same as a `UISwitch, it's just using different graphics.  Since we're using CALayer, the color transition is also animated for us.

```
//CustomSwitch.H
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CustomSwitch : UISwitch {
    CALayer* uiLayer; 
}

@end

//CustomSwitch.m

    #import "CustomSwitch.h"
    #import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

    @implementation CustomSwitch               

    -(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];                

        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(checked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        if (NULL!=self)
        {
            [self customLayout];
        }        

        return self;
    }

    -(void) checked:(id) event
    {
        uiLayer.backgroundColor=  [self isOn] ? [UIColor greenColor].CGColor : [UIColor redColor].CGColor;      
    }

    -(void) customLayout
    {
        uiLayer = [CALayer layer];            
        uiLayer.frame = self.frame;
        uiLayer.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor ].CGColor;         
        [[self layer] addSublayer:uiLayer];            
    }

    -(void)dealloc
    {
        [uiLayer release];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom UISwitch class and I'd like to share it.
You can download the custom UISwitch here:

http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2013/04/free-custom-uiswitch-flexible-colors.html

Cheers